Список сайтов с уязвимостями
Хочу немного похимичить, если у кого есть, дайте пожалуйста сайты XSS и SQLInjection уязвимостями

https://xss-game.appspot.com/

А я как-то нашел сайт с csrf-уязвимостью

Здравствуйте, спасибо огромное!

OWASP Broken Web Applications Project — это коллекция уязвимых веб-приложений, которые размещены в виртуальной машине.
Проект может быть интересен при:

изучении безопасности веб-приложений;
тестировании ручных методик
оценки;
тестировании автоматизированных инструментов;
тестировании
инструментов анализа исходного кода;
наблюдении за веб-атаками;
тестировании файрволов веб-приложений (WAF) и подобных технологий.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/owaspbwa/
